# Something stops me from installing Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

I’m trying to install Ubuntu on a Lenovo T410 which hasn’t been used for a while but the installation stops, giving me Help and Support box. What can I do to identify the problem?

Comment: could you tell us on which step the installation stop?

Comment: Tried again and got this: The ext4 file system creation in partition #1 of SCSI1 (0,0,0) (sda) failed

Comment: try to run a live image like gparted and check the disk integrity, disk could be broken

Comment: Sorry, I’m not sure how to do that AtomiX84 !

Comment: https://gparted.org/livecd.php download here the live and follow the instruction, once you run the installer check the disk.